# Determine background color of specific X,Y coordinate in a PowerShell window

Tags: powershell

Suppose I print 100 lines with random background colors in a PowerShell window. How can I determine the background color that is applied to a specific line and character after the fact?

I tried changing to a location and printing the console background color, but as I suspected, that displays the background color that is already set as the output default:

```
$pos = (Get-Host).UI.RawUI.CursorPosition
$pos.X = 10
$pos.Y = 10
(Get-Host).UI.RawUI.CursorPosition = $pos
Write-Host (Get-Host).UI.RawUI.BackgroundColor
```

Comment: Thanks @PetSerAl, that's exactly what I needed. I added an answer about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As PetSerAl pointed out in the comments, `$Host.UI.RawUI.GetBufferContents` is able to get the contents of arbitrary ranges from the buffer, including colors. I wrapped it in a function which I'll probably be using for this:

```
function Get-ColorsAtPosition {
    Param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [int]$x,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [int]$y
    )

    $colors = $Host.UI.RawUI.GetBufferContents(@{
        Left=$x; Right=$x; Top=$y; Bottom=$y;
    })
    return @{
        ForegroundColor=$colors.ForegroundColor;
        BackgroundColor=$colors.BackgroundColor;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
$c = Get-ColorsAtPosition -x 3 -y 5
$c.ForegroundColor # White
$c.BackgroundColor # Blue
```

Remember that the `-x` and `-y` are zero-indexed.